# Obsolete cryptography (SHA1) warning although certificate uses SHA256

Tags: tls, certificates, chrome, sha

I ordered a certificate with SHA256 from Comodo and was wondering why Chrome shows this message:

> Your connection is encrypted with obsolete cryptography.
>
> The connection is encrypted using AES_256_CBC, with SHA1 for message
> authentication and DHE_RSA as the key exchange mechanism.

It complains about SHA1 although the only certificate that uses SHA1 is the root certificate, which shouldn't be the problem. **Why does Chrome show the warning like this?**

Here is the result from the SSL Labs test (certificate information and cipher suites on the server):

*Path #1*

> [my domain]
> RSA 2048 bits (e 65537) / SHA256withRSA
>
> COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
> RSA 2048 bits (e 65537) / SHA384withRSA
>
> COMODO RSA Certification Authority
> RSA 4096 bits (e 65537) / SHA384withRSA

*Path #2*

> [my domain]
> RSA 2048 bits (e 65537) / SHA256withRSA
>
> COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
> RSA 2048 bits (e 65537) / SHA384withRSA
>
> COMODO RSA Certification Authority
> RSA 4096 bits (e 65537) / SHA384withRSA
>
> AddTrust External CA Root
> RSA 2048 bits (e 65537) / SHA1withRSA

*Cipher Suites*

> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA

**Note:** I know that AES_256_CBC isn't considered modern cryptography, so the warning about obsolete cryptography would still appear. I was just wondering about the SHA1 part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The error message is just misleading**

You said yourself:

> I know that AES_256_CBC isn't considered modern cryptography, so the warning about obsolete cryptography would still appear.

And that is why you get that message.

Now unfortunately the message itself is not very clearly phrased.

SHA-1 is used in several circumstances. And here the "SHA-1" refers to HMAC message authentication and not to its use inside certificates.

From the [Chromium TLS page](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/education/tls) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/tLi3o).):

> **Message Authentication**
>
> You may see:
>
> *“The connection is using [cipher] with SHA1 for message authentication.”*
>
> This actually means that the connection is using HMAC-SHA1 for data integrity, rather than as a certificate signing algorithm (e.g. sha1WithRSAEncryption). The HMAC construction is strong enough that it is not broken when used with SHA1 (or even MD5) as the hash function, so this is **not** currently deprecated.

**What to do**
Enable *and have the server prefer* a cipher suite that Chrome likes better. Namely: Something with forward secrecy and either AES-GCM or CHACHA20_POLY1305. (The TLS page recommends `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`.)

Since that is already in your list, all you have to do is change the server's preference for it.

Comment: Starting from Chrome 44, SHA1 will be changed to HMAC-SHA1. "The connection is encrypted using AES_256_CBC, with HMAC-SHA1 for message authentication and DHE_RSA as the key exchange mechanism."

Comment: So, why does SSL Labs give an "A" and Chrome consider it an error?

Comment: @MikeWills: that's weird. Should at most be a warning. Not an error. Can you share the URL?

Comment: I figured it out, we had one image being delivered over http. That caused the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Your certificate may use SHA-256, however you still have SHA-1 cipher suites enabled:

```
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
```

Disable these and the warning should go away.

### Edit in response to comment:

The Chrome cipher suites are as follows:

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305       0xCC13
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305     0xCC14
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256  0xCC15
```

[image: Cipher suites]

so the strongest choice from your server would have been `TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`. I can only think that you may have a configuration setup to prefer weaker ciphers for performance purposes?

Comment: But why does Chrome use it even though a better method is available?

Comment: @chrisklaussner: Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you! I accepted StackzOfZtuff's answer because of the explanation, but yours was equally helpful. :)